# Merge all the imports into a single first cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering if there is an extension or add-on available (preferably vscode or jupyter-notebook) that combines all the module `import`s into a single top (first) cell?

As many I have a tendancy of scattering around my imports as I conduct the research and leaving them in the cell doesn't feel right to me, hence, the question.